# Better approach of Update In DB table using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing update operation of a table column by using SQL-alchemy and it's taking huge time for updating on a database table column.  below is the code of my update

```
table_name = Table('table_name', metadata, Column('search_key', String, primary_key=True), Column('status', String))
                conn = self.engine_sql_staging.connect()
data = table_name.update().where(table_name.c.search_key == bindparam('_search_key')).values({'status': bindparam('status')})
                conn.execute(data, df.to_dict('records'))
```

I am using pandas data frame data to update DB table's data. so my question 
1.Is there any better approach to update in DB table's column by using pandas.

Or
2. Should I insert this data frame data into the DB table then I will do the update in DB level?

Comment: Is there a reason you are notusing to_sql. Basically using this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: @kmcodes i am updating value of a column not appending new values

Comment: df.to_sql("your_table", engine, if_exists="replace")

Comment: @kmcodes replace: Drop the table before inserting new values.  so my updating frame contain only 2 columns condition column and updating column so i can not use this